# Proper way to linebreak

Tags: line-breaking, best-practices

When not doing tables, it's `\\` or to leave a blank line. I heard a few times that `\\` should be avoided whenever possible. Thus, any doc with a bunch of different-line formulas would have lots of empty lines.

That makes it somewhat harder to navigate, and I don't really like that, so I'm using `\\` for simple docs. Is it wrong?

Edit: MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
$\d U = T\d S - P\d V$

$\d A = -S\d T - P\d V$

$\d H = T\d S + V\d P$

$\d G = -S\d T + V\d P$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Notice that ` \\ ` and a blank line are two *completely different* things; the latter ends the paragraph; the former, doesn't.

Comment: If you don't like the "look" of blank lines in your source code, you can always end the prior line with `\par` instead.  But as Gonzalo points out, a \\ and a `\par` are two separate things.

Comment: Blank lines make it *harder* to navigate? I find quite the opposite. What do you mean by 'different-line formulas'? This makes me think you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Is \newline any better?

Comment: `\newlline` and `\par` work quite well. The output file needs some space between the equations. In the code, I feel it's a waste to have almost double the lines even though it's readable to have one equation right below the other.

Comment: @Kurzd `\newline` and `\par` are completely different to each other (and you should almost never use either of them in a document). `\par` is the same as a blank line and is for _paragraph_ (not line) end. You should never have a blank line before (or in) a displayed math equation. Your question would be a lot easier to understand if you showed examples of the markup you are using

Comment: are you using display math for equations? `abc\[x=y\]abc` makes a math display with no need for `\\ ` Your description makes me think you are doing `abc\\$x=y$\\abc` which is wrong.

Comment: @JohnKormylo no `\newline` is usually the same as `\\ ` and equally wrong.

Comment: It seems you are doing something substantially wrong in your code. Right now, you got the answer that `\\ ` is wrong, but if you post any of your code, somebody will suggest some clean code for you.

Comment: If those equations are set on their own i.e. not part of the flow of text, you shouldn't mark them as *inline* maths which is what `$...$` does. Display maths `\[...\]` is the obvious solution here. You absolutely ought not redefine `\d` !!

Comment: @cfr if more than one equation is one after the other (or a single equation is in multiple lines) one should use `amsmath` environments like `gather` or `align`. In any case, one *should* not redefine `\d` (plus there's nothing wrong with expandind `\d` to work in math mode —differential— and text mode —dot accent—).

Comment: @Manuel. I didn't really mean for the example: just not part of the flow. I would try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\myd}{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
 No alignment, unnumbered equation group:
  \begin{gather*}
 \myd U = T\myd S - P\myd V\\
 \myd A = -S\myd T - P\myd V\\
 \myd H = T\myd S + V\myd P\\
 \myd G = -S\myd T + V\myd P
  \end{gather*}
  
Aligned, unnumbered equation group:
  \begin{align*}
 \myd U &= T\myd S - P\myd V\\
 \myd A &= -S\myd T - P\myd V\\
 \myd H &= T\myd S + V\myd P\\
 \myd G &= -S\myd T + V\myd P
  \end{align*}
\end{document}`.

Comment: It's just a reference sheet, and `\[...\]` spaces them too much in the output. There's minimal text on them. How bad is to redefine `\d`? I'm not using the original command at all.

Comment: I can't post the above as an answer so the formatting is not at all neat, but this is the kind of strategy you should be thinking about.

Comment: It looks claner. Still, what's the bad thing about redefining `\d`?

Comment: @Kurzd Do you know what the definition of `\d` is? Do you know whether any other commands in the class or packages you use rely on it? Not using a command explicitly doesn't mean you aren't using it. Maybe the answer is that you are not using anything which requires it. But unless you have checked and are sure, you shouldn't redefine it. Doing this also makes your code less flexible. You can't copy these equations to another document, with the definition, and just use them without checking whether it is safe in the new document. You can't submit or share a document which does this. Etc.

Comment: I'm convinced now. Am I allowed to thank you all? @Manuel are command expansions the things that begin with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really need here is one or other environment from `amsmath`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% few enhancements; loads amsmath
\newcommand*{\myd}{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
 No alignment, unnumbered equation group:
  \begin{gather*}
    \myd U = T\myd S - P\myd V\\
    \myd A = -S\myd T - P\myd V\\
    \myd H = T\myd S + V\myd P\\
    \myd G = -S\myd T + V\myd P
  \end{gather*}

Aligned, unnumbered equation group:
  \begin{align*}
    \myd U &= T\myd S - P\myd V\\
    \myd A &= -S\myd T - P\myd V\\
    \myd H &= T\myd S + V\myd P\\
    \myd G &= -S\myd T + V\myd P
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: grouped equations]